# how to show a scroll bar in lwuit form?

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form

I have a lwuit form . The form's layout has been set to BorderLayout. Then, I have added a container to the form.

ie. form.addComponent(BorderLayout.Center, some_COntainer);

This container consist of several items like..containers,text areas and buttons. As a result the form extends well beyond the mobile screen.

How do I show a vertical scroll bar in the form so that the user know that the form extends beyond the screen?

Right now, there is no scroll bar visible. How do i do this?

This is what I tried:

```
Form myForm = new Form("xyz");
myForm.setScrollable(false);

Container container = new Container();
TextArea message = new TextArea("A very long message here which goes beyond the screen length");

container.setLaynout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_axis));
container.add(message);
container.add(new RadioButton("a1"));
container.add(new RadioButton("a2"));
container.add(new RadioButton("a3"));
container.add(new RadioButton("a4"));
container.add(new RadioButton("a5"));
container.add(new RadioButton("a6"));
container.add(new RadioButton("a7"));
container.add(new Button("press me"));
myform.addComponenet(container);
container.setScrollable(true);
```

Now, I would like the scroll bar to be visible inside the container. But its not working. Am I missing out on anything?

Answer (score 0):

Border layout isn't very good at scrolling. By default forms are scrollable on the Y axis in LWUIT and you can enable/disable this using `setScrollableY(true/false);` appropriately.

Edited since you changed the question completely, I don't even understand what you are trying to do. This code will do what it seems you are trying to accomplish without all the hoops:

```
Form myForm = new Form("xyz");

TextArea message = new TextArea("A very long message here which goes beyond the screen length");

myForm.setLaynout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_axis));
myForm.add(new RadioButton("a1"));
myForm.add(new RadioButton("a2"));
```

Comment: I have kept my form scrollable. But how do i show the scrollbar on the right?

Comment: Then disable your form's scrollability and enable the Y scrollability to the container inside. Border layouts don't scroll well because conceptually they aren't designed for that.

Comment: I have edited this post and added some code. Please let me know if you think I am missing out on something.